# what sources of information / videos do you use to learn new techniques for webdevelopment with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, model-view-controller, video-streaming

I work at a company that makes the move from php to .net.
Now i am searching for good video sources to learn new techniques.

We have already a license for www.tekpub.com great site
but already have seen a lot of movies and will check other video sources too

what video sources do you have or do you know ?

Comment: Should be Community Wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a move from php, it is WebDevelopment and for that

- [**Asp.net/learn**](http://Asp.net/learn)
- [**aspnet-channel9**](http://weblogs.asp.net/aspnet-channel9/default.aspx)

**EDIT:**
for MVC see this starter Vid

- [**ASP.NET MVC 1 with Phil Haack**](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/ASPNET-MVC-1-with-Phil-Haack/)

Comment: yes it is for web development, build website for years in php but now we have made the choice for .net with mvc

Comment: have updated with link for MVC, you will get a whole section dedicated to MVC at www.Asp.Net/learn

Answer (score 4):

Here a list with screencast that i have see and found

http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/screencasts/

http://www.tekpub.com

http://www.asp.net/learn/

http://channel9.msdn.com/Media/Screencasts/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET35ExtensionsPlusMVCHowToScreencast.aspx

http://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/screencasts.mvc

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/01/17/10130.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have used www.msdn.com for C#.Net  They have documentation, tutorials, videos, forums, etc.  I would recommend going that route at least for starters